# Empty array don't appear as empty in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

Right now I'm trying to check when the view receives an empty array.

```
@if(! empty($array))
    // Section content goes here...

    @foreach($array as $value)
        // All table data goes here... 
    @endforeach
@endif
```

The code as it is above seems to still run when the `$array` is empty and causes an exception.

When I try to dump the array with `{{ dd($array) }}` I get `$array = []`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you might be having a collection. You could simply do `count($array)` to check amount of records in the array. It would look something like this:

```
@if(count($array))
    // Section content goes here...

    @foreach($array as $value)
        // All table data goes here... 
    @endforeach
@endif
```

The section should now be hidden. If you wish to only skip the foreach when there is nothing in the array you could do this:

```
// Section content goes here...

@forelse($array as $value)
    // All table data goes here...
@empty
    // Optional message if it's empty
@endforelse
```

Which would output the section content and check if the array has any values before it `foreach` it.

You can read more about loops within blade files in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#loops).

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible your array is a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections)?

Try using a [`@forelse`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#loops), this will check if the array or collection is empty and display another block instead. For example:

```
@forelse($array as $value)
    {{ $value }}
@empty
    array is empty
@endforelse
```

Comment: Thanks, but I needed to hide the whole section when there was no content.